# Import method from __init__.py

Tags: python, python-module

Having some issues with importing modules in python. This is my folder structure

```
my_app/
    app.py
    __init__.py (I want to import a function from this file)
    folder1/
        __init.py
        method1.py
    folder2/
        __init__.py
        method.py
```

In my root `__init__.py` I have this function

```
def want_to_be_run_elsewhere():
    pass
```

In my app.py, I want to import this function and run it when I start my application, but I'm unsure how to do it.

```
from my_app import want_to_be_run_elsewhere
```

This throws a no module named my_app

From what I can tell, I have all the necessary `__init__.py` files, so maybe it could be sys.path related?

I've read some similar threads on here but I haven't been able to solve this.

Comment: Are `app.py` and `__init__.py` inside `my_app/` or not?

Comment: Sorry for the sloppiness. Yes `app.py` and `__init__.py` is inside my_app/ and `app.py` is my entry point

Comment: FWIW, it's not usual to define functions inside a `__init__.py` file. They are normally empty, or just have an `__all__` list in them.

Comment: Hmmm, OK. Maybe I should just consider moving the function then. I don't wanna import `__init__``but if that's the only way, I think i'll implement it another way. Thanks!

Comment: Simplest way to figure this out which I always prefer is, try it importing in ipython with tab key. E.g. : import something. <tab>

Comment: Are you running the script as `python my_app/app.py`? Then **don't do that!** Either write an external script, so you'd have `app.py` **outside** the `my_app` folder, or use the `-m` switch: `python -m my_app.app`

Comment: @Bakuriu, we don't need to run app.py. Normally we run a main script where it import app.py. Then some functions can be imported from ___init___.py because there might be several modules such as app1.py, app2.py, etc which share the same functions. So, I also keep some functions in ___init___.py. But it would be better idea to make a common module such as aux.py then import from it.

Answer (score 9):

Usually you would do the import like

```
from . import want_to_be_run_elsewhere
```

This doesn't work here, because you are calling `app.py`. If you import `my_app.app`, it is part of the module. If you call it it is not. Importing from the module it is in using `.` will then not work.

You could either move `app.py` outside of `my_app`, removing it from the module and making imports work again.

Or you can use

```
from __init__ import want_to_be_run_elsewhere
```

in `app.py`

I believe

```
from my_app import want_to_be_run_elsewhere
```

will only work if you have actually `pip install -e my_app/`. Then it should work too.

Comment: Alternatively, invoke `app.py` as a module in the package: From the dir **above** `my_app`, call `python -m my_app.app` or `python3 -m my_app.app`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11536794/674064

Comment: Interesting! will have to try this

Comment: I'd remove the suggestion to use `from __init__ import ...`. It's not the right way of doing things. It can even break code if some code in the submodules depends on the package name (e.g. if you use modules like `pickle` directly or `shleve` etc using that solution will make data unreadable).